# Detach Boot Disk from GCE VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to detach the Boot Disk from a GCE VM. As the VM is stopped so it should allow me to detach it but it's returning this error

```
UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION: Hot-remove of the root disk is not supported.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your high-level goal? See my answer as to why you can't detach the without deleting the VM, but depending on what you're trying to achieve, there may be other solutions available.

Comment: FYI, as of [24 Jan 2019](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes#January_24_2019), GCE added the ability to [detach and reattach boot disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk) from stopped VMs in GA.

Answer (score 6):

#### Updated answer

As of [24 Jan 2019](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes#January_24_2019), GCE added the ability to [detach and reattach boot disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk) from stopped VMs in GA.

---

#### Original answer (correct prior to 24 Jan 2019)

If you detach the boot disk from a stopped VM, there's no way to restart the VM back up, so that operation does not make sense.

Thus, you would need to disable the option ["auto-delete boot disk"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#updateautodelete) and delete the VM:

> To set the auto delete state of a persistent disk in `gcloud compute`, use the [`gcloud compute instances set-disk-auto-delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-disk-auto-delete) command:

> ```
> gcloud compute instances set-disk-auto-delete INSTANCE \
> ```

```
    [--auto-delete | --no-auto-delete] --disk DISK --zone ZONE
```

Alternatively, you can also change this setting on the VM details page from the Developers Console by clicking on the VM instance name, and then unchecking this option:

> ☐ Delete boot disk when instance is deleted

Comment: The operation makes sense.  You would just have to re-attach the disk after you were finished with whatever you were trying to do (e.g. create an image).  Also, `set-disk-auto-delete` had no effect on my instance.  But unchecking the equivalent option in the web UI worked.

Comment: Why isn't there a way to restart the VM back up if I reattach the boot disk later? At AWS it's no problem.

Comment: @RustyX – if you want to keep the VM (e.g., to keep its parameters or meta data), don't delete it, instead just [Stop](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance) it, and you can start it up again in the future.

Comment: @RustyX — apologies if I misunderstood your use case; certainly not intentional. That said, no need to insult people who spend time answering questions by calling them bots. I assumed you're either looking to (a) create a new VM from a boot disk (after deleting it, but keeping the disk), (b) suspend a VM and resume it later, or (c) turn it off (without deleting the VM) and turn it back on later. You can do all of these, and I assumed you asked about (c) since you said "restart", but sounds like I misunderstood. What exactly are you trying to do? What AWS feature are you referring to?

Comment: @RustyX — let me see if I understand you correctly. You have a VM, you shut it down, you detach the boot disk. Then later on, you re-attach the same boot disk to the VM, and you're saying you cannot boot the VM back up? If so, that sounds like a bug, it should certainly work. If you have a support plan, please file a support ticket. If you don't have a support plan, find me on Twitter or LinkedIn and we can connect to discuss further. If this is still not capturing your use case, please clarify what you meant.

Comment: @MishaBrukman - sorry about the misunderstanding, I honestly thought that was the only explanation for the general comment that had little relation to the topic of this thread. Anyway the issue is that it is impossible to detach the boot disk without deleting the VM, even if the VM is stopped. The VM must be deleted in order to release the boot disk. AWS has no such limitation other than that the VM must not be running.

Comment: @RustyX — thanks for the clarification, now I understand the issue. I'm reaching out to the GCE experts to get you an answer.

Comment: @RustyX — I checked with the GCE gurus, they confirmed this feature is not available (as you noticed), and are curious what the motivation/use case is behind the request, to help them prioritize this feature on the backlog. Would you be open to connecting on LinkedIn or Twitter DM and describing your use case in more detail?

Comment: @MishaBrukman I missed that twice so far. There is a corruption or misconfiguration on the boot disk, I want to fix it by attaching it to another VM, then move it back to this one so that it can boot again.As it is not possible I have to delete this VM and recreate another one later, re-assign it the static IP, re-add it to instance group, etc. Or alternatively I would want to restore a snapshot of the boot disk which is not possible for the same reason.

Comment: @CMoi — thanks for the detailed description of your use case! I shared it with the GCE PM team.

Comment: FWIW, for anyone following along and interested in this feature, as of [24 Jan 2019](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes#January_24_2019), GCE added the ability to [detach and reattach boot disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk) from stopped VMs in GA. Apologies for not posting an update on this earlier as I hadn't noticed this was launched.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hot-remove the root disk of a VM otherwise you'd render it unusable (shutdown assumes you want to start the VM at a later point). Instead, you can delete the VM instance, making sure to preserve the root disk for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Detaching boot disks is now supported in Beta ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk)). After shutting down instance, try: `gcloud beta compute instances detach-disk INSTANCE_NAME --disk DISK_NAME`

To re-attach a boot disk to the instance: `gcloud beta compute instances attach-disk INSTANCE_NAME --disk DISK_NAME --boot`